# Input type file in Chrome will not popup when served via https

Tags: html, google-chrome

File input boxes aren't working in Chrome for me, I have reduced this down to pretty much just a single input box, and it still doesn't work.  Works in IE and FireFox, and Edge.  What can I do to get this to work?  Using version 88.0.4324.190.  It works in Chrome if I just get the file from the file system or via IIS and a http connection, but it doesn't work if the connection is https, despite there being no certificate problems.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>
        Input type file not working
    </title>
</head>
<body>
    <form name="aspnetForm" method="post" action="./test.aspx" id="aspnetForm" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="file" name="atest" id="atestid" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: No console errors? When you say that it doesn't work, what exactly do you mean? Does it not show up? Does it show up but there's no dialog when you click the button?

Comment: @j08691: The dialog box doesn't show up (so you can't pick a file).  No console errors, everything seems to be fine.  I just checked again, and it is now working (both on my regular page and the test page where I reduced it down to just the above).  Guess I'll close it as non-reproducible.  Scratching my head...